# Sinalizando o ultimo resgistro do SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
select cod_nota, cod_local, cod_produto, valor from pedido
order by
cod_nota,cod_local,cod_produto
```

Com o  resultado:

```
|cod_nota|cod_local|cod_produto| Valor | 
|  501   |   01    |   124714  | 150,00|
|  501   |   01    |   328180  | 120,00|
|  501   |   260   |   58014   | 100,00|
|  502   |   10    |   24587   | 50,00 | 
|  502   |   10    |   154547  | 20,00 |
|  502   |   10    |   154547  | 189,00|
|  502   |   15    |   24587   | 50,00 | 
|  503   |   10    |   154547  | 20,00 |
|  503   |   10    |   154547  | 189,00|
```

Desejo ter o seguinte resultado:

```
|cod_nota|cod_local|cod_produto| Valor |ULtimo| 
|  501   |   01    |   124714  | 150,00|      |
|  501   |   01    |   328180  | 120,00|  S   |
|  501   |   260   |   58014   | 100,00|  S   |
|  502   |   10    |   24587   | 50,00 |      | 
|  502   |   10    |   154547  | 20,00 |      |
|  502   |   10    |   154547  | 189,00|  S   |
|  502   |   15    |   24587   | 50,00 |  S   | 
|  503   |   10    |   154547  | 20,00 |      |
|  503   |   10    |   154547  | 189,00|  S   |
```

Onde estou marcando um "S" na ultima nota do Local.

Comment: Creio que precisa algo para identificar o "maior"

Comment: Isso mesmo quero identificar o maior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que último é não ter produto* maior no mesmo local/nota , 
faço um subselect na mesma tabela contando os maiores se maior que zero não é último , se não é.

```
select cod_nota, cod_local, cod_produto, valor  ,
       (select (case when count(*) > 0 then 'n' else 's' end) ultimo
        from  pedido p2 
        where p2.cod_local = p1.cod_local
        and   p2.cod_nota = p1.cod_nota
        and   p2.cod_produto > p1.cod_produto)
from pedido p1
order by cod_nota,cod_local,cod_produto
```

o subselect simula uma coluna , ele conta as notas que existam e são "maiores" que a nota da linha em questão , sendo maior que zero não é a "última" , sendo = 0 é a "última"

- acho estranho fazer pelo produto (teria outra chave) ?

Comment: Legal funcionou. Só não entendi internamente como é feito esse subselect, mas ta valendo.

Comment: Editada a solução para explicação

Comment: Como eu faria para identificar o intervalo dos registros, por exemplo, gostaria de identificar o ultimo registro no intervalo de cada 3 registros e marcar com 'F', e continuando identificando o ultimo com 'F'.